# Regex first three characters, then only numbers or characters, optionally followed by two digits

Tags: regex, vba

I am trying to create a regex that will match first three characters at the beginning, then digits or characters followed by (optionally) one character followed by two digits. The maximum length is 25.

```
BER12345 - match
BER123456A10 - match
```

My attempt: `^(?=[A-Z]{3,25}$)[A-Z0-9]{5,20}[0-9]{0,2]$`

Comment: Have you tried https://regex101.com/ ? There you can test your regex and there are also good explanations of how to get what you want.

Comment: These rules are not very clear. At least to me. Could you elaborate **and** include your own attempt at solving this.

Comment: "^(?=[A-Z]{3,25}$)[A-Z0-9]{5,20}[0-9]{0,2]$"
I am having the problem with max.length, and it matches also 0BER1234 (a digit at the beginning), it should be only first three characters followed by numbers, and after that can be one character followed by only two digits. Max. length of whole string should be 25.

Comment: *"it should be only first three characters followed by numbers"* is a bit different to *" match first three characters at the beginning, then digits **or** characters"*. I'm still confused with what exactly you need.

Comment: I would suggest to edit your question and place more examples, some of them to not match, and explain **why not matching**. We maybe will better understand the rules to be applied...

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

`(^[A-Z]{3}[A-Z0-9]{1,19}[A-Z0-9]\d{2}$)|(^[A-Z]{3}[A-Z0-9]{1,22}$)` [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uSHBTo/1)

```
BER - no match (desn't have digits or chars after begining)
BER456 - match
BER12345 - match
BER123456A10 - match
BER12345678910dasdd123 - no match (lowercase)
BER1234567890123456789123 - match (only numbers) 
BER1234S67890AFF456789123 - match (uppercase) 
BER1234S67890AFF4567891DA - match (with letters at the end) 
BER12345678989A10dasdd123 - no match (lowercase)
BER1234S67890AFF456789123A - no match (max size)
BER1234567890123456789A10AAA123 - no match (max size)
```

If you want to match the first example above with only 3 chars `BER` , just change `{1,19}` and `{1,22}` to `{0,19}` and `{0,22}`